# How can I bound a block of text with a pair of vertical lines using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

MWE:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=DarkBlue,line width=1.0pt,inner sep=12pt,inner ysep=6pt]
\node at (0,0) [rectangle,draw,fill=LightBlue]{ % 
\begin{minipage}[t]{118mm} %

A wide block of text contained in a complete rectangle.

I want only the left and right lines to appear.

i. e. open at the top and the bottom, but keep the shading.\vspace{3pt}

Tried adapting the line commented-out below, but cannot control placement.\vspace{2pt}
% \draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (0,-1) -- (2,-1) node [right] {\SI{0.25}{\milli\meter}};;
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: An unrelated note: Instead of adding a `minipage` inside the node, why not just add `text width=118mm` to the node options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name the node and separately draw lines between the corners:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=blue!60!black,line width=1.0pt,inner sep=12pt,inner ysep=6pt]
\node[rectangle, outer sep=0pt, fill=blue!10!white] (text node) at (0,0) { %
\begin{minipage}[t]{118mm} %

A wide block of text contained in a complete rectangle.

I want only the left and right lines to appear.

i. e. open at the top and the bottom, but keep the shading.\vspace{3pt}

Tried adapting the line commented-out below, but cannot control placement.\vspace{2pt}
% \draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (0,-1) -- (2,-1) node [right] {\SI{0.25}{\milli\meter}};;
\end{minipage}};
\draw (text node.south west) -- (text node.north west) (text node.south east) -- (text node.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know OP wants a `TiKZ` solution, but may be he doesn't know [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) which main goal is producing colorful text boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
notitle,
colback=blue!10!white,
colframe=blue!60!black,
sharp corners,
boxsep=0pt,
left=12pt, right=12pt,
top=6pt, bottom=6pt,
boxrule=0pt,leftrule=1pt,rightrule=1pt,
width=#2,
#1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{118mm}
A wide block of text contained in a complete rectangle.

I want only the left and right lines to appear.

i. e. open at the top and the bottom, but keep the shading.

Tried adapting the line commented-out below, but cannot control placement.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[colback=red!30]{60mm}
A wide block of text contained in a complete rectangle.

I want only the left and right lines to appear.

i. e. open at the top and the bottom, but keep the shading.

Tried adapting the line commented-out below, but cannot control placement.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ignasi - same result!  Is there any fundamental advantage in using \tcolorbox?

Comment: Ignasi - your method does not directly involves nodes?  Would it be possible to insert an eps figure, say, before the word "Tried".  I have a theorem which requires a figure to be placed within the text.  I have tried but it gives an error: "not in outer par mode".

Comment: @keith77777: `tcolorbox` main goal is producing color boxes. If you just need this, I think it's better to use a package suited to this topic (`mdframed` is another one) instead of `TiKZ` which is a graphics tool. In fact `tcolorbox` uses `TiKZ` behind the front end. A big advantage is its capability for breakable (between pages) boxes, your solution cannot cope with them. Take a look at [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox)  and decide about using it or not.

Comment: @keith77777 It can insert graphics inside the box, but you mention `figure` which is a floating object. I'd suggest updating your question or writing a new one with the real problem you want to solve.

Comment: I can forfeit the figure and use just a graphic since the therem is self-contained.  Seems like tcolorbox and even tikz are like using sledgehammers to crack a nut!  I will formulate a new question.  Thanks.